# Simulating continuous inputs on stdin and scanning lines

Tags: go, stdin, tty

My program normally uses the controlling terminal to read input from the user.

```golang
// GetCtty gets the file descriptor of the controlling terminal.
func GetCtty() (*os.File, error) {
    return os.OpenFile("/dev/tty", os.O_RDONLY, 0)
}
```

I am currently constructing **several times** a `s := bufio.NewScanner(GetCtty())` during the programm and read the input from `s.Scan()` with `s.Text()`. Which works nice.

However, for testing I am simulating the following input on stdin to my CLI Go-Program

```sh
echo -e "yes\nno\nyes\n" | app
```

This will not work correctly because the first construction of `s` and `s.Scan()` will already have **buffered** other test inputs which will not be available to a new construction by `bufio.NewScanner` and subsequent scan.

I am wondering how I can make sure that only **one line** is read from the stdin stream by `s *bufio.Scanner` or how I can mock my input to the controlling terminal.

I had several guesses but I am not sure if they work:

- using only one `bufio.Scanner` in the whole program is a solution but I did not want to go this way...
- write back the buffered data to `GetCtty()` with `s.WriteTo(GetCtty())` (?) want work as the stuff gets appended instead of prepended on stdin?
- Somehow only read a single line and do not consume more bytes, does that untimately mean to read not in chunks but byte by bytes (?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [iotest.OneByteReader](https://godoc.org/testing/iotest#OneByteReader) to disable buffering in the scanner:

```
s := bufio.NewScanner(iotest.OneByteReader(GetCtty()))
```

Comment: Haha very nice, that is awesome... And its even supposed for tests.